# How to get the AWS Access key of an already created Access ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iam

Inside `IAM management`, I navigate to `Users - User` and got to the `Security Credentials` tab, It looks like this:

[image: aim]

I see no link to show the `access key` of the already generated `access ID`, how to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Access Key** is that `AKIA...` one. What you need is a **Secret Key** - that can't be recovered after the initial setup.

Since you have never used this particular access key (it says "Last used: N/A") it's safe to *Make inactive* and then *Delete* and then create a new one through **Create access key** button above the form.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: So, it they cannot be read after initial setup, that is the way AWS works?

Comment: @W.M. exactly, can only be "seen" or "downloaded" once when created and thats it.

Comment: @W.M. please note upon creation of a Access Key the system will tell you on that page that you must copy the information and/or download the csv file. Once you leave that page you will never again be able to obtain the `secret`. This is a security measure to protect your deployed instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can download or read the **Secret Key** only when you set it up for the first time.

If you lost the **Secret Key** / didn't manage to save it and is not being used anywhere, it is better to *Delete* and create a new one.

Don't forget to copy the **Secret Key** before you move to any other screen this time :)